# Subclass var initialization step and OOP structure design

Tags: oop, inheritance, methods, kotlin, overriding

The abstract super class `Parent` has abstract method `extract(Int)`, getting the value `a` from primary constructor, and submit it to that method `extract(a)`.

```
abstract class Parent ( val a : Int ) {

    abstract fun extract ( i : Int )

    init {
        // call overriden extract(Int)
        extract ( a )
    }
}
```

The sub class `Child` defines the method `extract(Int)`, sending the value `b` to the `Parent`'s constructor, then the super class `Parent` calling `extract(Int)` to set that value to `Child`'s variable `x`.

```
class Child ( b : Int ) : Parent ( b ) {

    // initialize x variable to -1
    var x : Int = -1

    override fun extract ( i : Int ) {
        // set x to given int
        x = i
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
println ( Child ( 10 ).x )
```

And got:

```
-1
```

Now, try adding `init{}` of the sub class `Child`

```
    init {
        x = -2
    }
```

Testing again:

```
println ( Child ( 10 ).x )
```

And got:

```
-2
```

Seemingly, the `init{}` of sub class `Child` is done after the super class `Parent`'s construction.

Should the `extract(Int)` be overridden ann called by all sub classes, rather than by the super class?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "super class `Child`", but it seems you may be confused of the order of derived classes. Here is a really good [example that shows the order](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#derived-class-initialization-order). It has a code snippet that you can run on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking this kind of initializer interaction is frowned upon, since the exact order of operations, while well defined, is often counter-intuitive.

Specifically, what I *believe* is happening here, might be more clear using the more verbose explicit-constructor syntax in kotlin. You're code is an abbreviated version of this (note, this is legal kotlin):

```
abstract class Parent {

    val a: Int

    constructor(a: Int){
        this.a = a
        extract(a)
    }

    abstract fun extract ( i : Int )
}

class Child: Parent {

    var x : Int

    constructor(b: Int): Parent(b) {
        //super.constructor(b) fires here

        // initialize x variable to -1 
        x = -1
    }

    override fun extract (i : Int) {
        // set x to given int
        x = i
    }
}
```

thus, as I hope is now a little more clear, a pseudo-call-trace is like this:

> 1. enter `Child.constructor(10)`
> 2. enter `Parent.constructor(10)`
> 3. assign 10 to `this@Parent.a`
> 4. enter `this.extract(10)` => V-Table resolves `Child.extract()`
> 5. assign 10 to `this@Child.x`
> 6. `extract` returns
> 7. `Parent.constructor` returns
> 8. assign -1 to `this@Child.x` *this is probably your point of confusion*
> 9. `Child.constructor` returns

### What you can do

Generally speaking, when you encounter confusing initialization flows, the answer on the JVM is to formalize the complex initialization in **another method**, rather than in more `init` or `constructors`.

In kotlin the simplest way to do this --and a strategy used by many many libraries-- is to create a static factory method.

```
abstract class Parent(val a: Int) {
  //...
}

class Child private constructor(var x: Int): Parent(x) {

    companion object {

        fun makeChild(unextracted: Int) {
            val extracted = extract(unextracted)
            return Child(extracted)
        }

        // a first good step is to make `extract` referentially transparent 
        // aka pure
        // IE all of its function is provided in its return type
        fun extract (i : Int): Int {
            return i //do appropriate transforms.
            //note, if you need multiple return values here, consider Pairs or Triples. 
        }
    }
}
```

> Note, kotlin provides some syntax sugar for this, you can override the invoke operator:
>
> `class Child { companion object { operator fun invoke(x: Int) { ... } } }`
>
> which means that instead of `makeChild` (eg `Child.makeChild(10)`) to call your factory function you to use ~constructor syntax (`Child(10)`).

Even more generally, if you find yourself running into this problem under an IOC container which, for whatever reason, *must* use initializer flow, I would encourage you to refactor your IOC consumers to use old-fashioned java factories. I'll need more details to elaborate here.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. i'm figuring out what IOC stuff actually is; I'm newbie, really.

Thinking about my imagination, the `Parent` shouldn't be "parent"; the _super class_ is like a conceptual thing that can extract data, while any _sub class_ can extract in various method. So, in your suggestion, all _sub classes_ should make quite similar `fun makeChild(..)` pattern?